# Как правильно ограничить ширину элемента равную его содержимому (html/css)?

Tags: html, css

Допустим, имеется несколько элементов в колонку, второму элементу необходимо ограничить ширину так, чтобы она была равна ширине его контента. Как это грамотно сделать?

```css
.list
{}

.list__item
{
  background: bisque;
}

.item-2
{
  background: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item item-1">item 1</div>
  <div class="list__item item-2">item 2</div>
  <div class="list__item item-3">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого подходит `display: inline-block`:

```css
.list__item {
  background: bisque;
}

.item-2 {
  background: burlywood;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item item-1">item 1</div>
  <div class="list__item item-2">item 2</div>
  <div class="list__item item-3">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если надо оставить элементы блочными, можно заюзать `width: max-content`.

```css
.list__item {
  background: bisque;
  width: max-content;
}

.item-2 {
  background: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item item-1">item 1</div>
  <div class="list__item item-2">item 2 is a little bigger</div>
  <div class="list__item item-3">item 3</div>
</div>
```